# displaying contact list in a fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I am a newbie in android. So here is my problem.I have a requirement to generate contact list in fragment.I already tried extending listActivity and listFragment. In list activity I'm getting the result but when using listFragment there is no error, but application is crashing. Here is my full code.

Invite.java

```
    package com.kicka;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.kicka.R;

    public class Invite extends Activity {

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.invite_friends);



        }

        public void fbInvite(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FindFbFriends.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        public void contactInvite(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FindPhnFriends.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

FindPhnFriends.java

```
    package com.kicka;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class FindPhnFriends extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_contact_find_friend);

    }    


}
```

fragment_contact_find_friend.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ff5240"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="14dp"
                    android:text="Invite Your Contacts"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="serif" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Add friends to share Perks and earn rewards!"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>

             <fragment
                android:id="@+id/phn_contacts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                class="com.kicka.PhnContact"
                /> 

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

PhnContact.java

```
package com.kicka;


import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class PhnContact extends ListFragment{



    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Cursor cur = getContacts();

        ListView lv = getListView();

       String[] fields = new String[] {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};


    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = 
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), 
                                        R.layout.phone_contacts_list,
                                        cur,
                                        fields,
                                        new int[] {R.id.phn_contact_name});
          lv.setAdapter(adapter);         
    } 





    private Cursor getContacts() {  
        // Run query     
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = 
                new String[]{ ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                              ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME }; 
            String selection = null;
            String[] selectionArgs = null;  
            String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + 
                " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";  
            return getActivity().managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    }

}
```

phone_contacts_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#f7f7f8" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/phn_contact_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/kick_a"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phn_contact_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:lines="2"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:text="FirstName LastName"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceButton" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/phn_contact_select"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:checked="false"
        android:button="@drawable/plus" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What error it thrown? Post your stack trace.

Comment: Stack Trace: content view not yet created.